# 100% высота блока в React

Tags: css, reactjs

С помощью npm установил **React**. Из "коробки" существует файл *App.js*. Сделал разметку:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header/Header.js'
import Main from './components/main/Main.js'

const App = () => {
  return ( 
    <div className = "App" >
      <Header / >
      <Main / >
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**header** у меня фиксированной высоты в 80px. А вот **main** надо растянуть на всю оставшуюся высоту.

Пробовал решить с помощью **гридов**:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
```

Пробовал с помощью **флексов**. По дефолту в *align-items* = *stetch*. Думал, растянется, но нет. Задавал App'у высоту в 100%. Но ничего не работает.
Есть варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что у Вас ничего не работает, так как `main` пустой и Вы указываете дочерним элементам занять всю высоту `body`, но вот высоту для самого `body` по всей видимости, не задали. А ведь его высота равна высоте внутреннего контента.

Не знаю, какая у Вас конечная цель, но для примера можете попробовать для `body` задать `min-height: 100vh`.

Comment: Забыл уточнить, но я пробовал это. + App задал 100%. Но нет :(